# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined: document.getElementsByName.onmouseenter

Tags: javascript

I have 2 files:
`index.html` and `code.js`

I have 2 problems:

First, the "Find word:" sentence does not appear in the browser.

Second, I have a for loop that creates a table(10x10). This table contains random letters, and I want to color the background of the letter that I am hovering over with my mouse, but I get the same error every time I hover: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined: document.getElementsByName.onmouseenter`

```js
document.write("Find word:");

var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

var s='<table border= "1" >';
for(var j=0;j<10;++j)
{
  s+='<tr height="30px">'; 
  for(var i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
   s +='<td width="20px" align="center" id="letter" name="letter">'+ possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))+'</td>'; 
    }
  s+='</tr>'; 
}
s+='</table>'; 

document.body.innerHTML=s;


for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByName('letter').length;i++)
{
 document.getElementsByName('letter')[i].onmouseenter=function(){
  document.getElementsByName('letter')[i].style.backgroundColor="red";
 };
}
```

```html
<script src="code.js"></script>
```

Comment: "Find word:" is disappearing because after you write it to the document, you're replacing the entire html contents of the document with your generated table.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `this` inside the onmouseenter function to indicate the element you want to change.

```js
document.write("Find word:");

var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

var s='<table border= "1" >';
for(var j=0;j<10;++j)
{
  s+='<tr height="30px">'; 
  for(var i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
   s +=  '<td width="20px" align="center" id="letter" name="letter">'+ possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))+'</td>'; 
    }
  s+='</tr>'; 
}
s+='</table>'; 

document.body.innerHTML=s;


for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByName('letter').length;i++)
{
 document.getElementsByName('letter')[i].onmouseenter=function(){
  this.style.backgroundColor="red";
 };
}
```

```html
<script src="code.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I am new in JS, but yes it was an epic fail from me I guess :D

Comment: no problem! :) you can accept the answer so that I get some stackoverflow karma

Comment: I need 15 reputation, but asap I will :)

Comment: You don't indicate *why* the given code in the question doesn't work, which would probably be useful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
document.getElementsByName('letter')[i].style.backgroundColor="red";
```

The `mouseenter` listener is overwritten on every run of the `for` loop, so `i` always equals 100. Instead, try using `this` to refer to the element that you're attaching the listener to:

```
this.style.backgroundColor="red";
```

```js
document.body.innerHTML = ("Find word:<br/><br/>");

var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

var s = '<table border= "1" >';
for (var j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
  s += '<tr height="30px">';
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    s += '<td width="20px" align="center" id="letter" name="letter">' + possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)) + '</td>';
  }
  s += '</tr>';
}
s += '</table>';

document.body.innerHTML += s;


for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('letter').length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByName('letter')[i].onmouseenter = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="code.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply use css ?

```
td:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

and BTW, you write "Find Word:" body but override the entire body doing *document.body.innerHTML=s;* ...
you must prepend your firt sentence or, better, provide an html with your title and a dedicated div in your body to build your table.